# Error in doc_parse_raw(x, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html, : internal error: Huge input lookup [1]

Tags: r

When I am exporting the data frame into Microsoft word format, I am getting the error "Huge input lookup".

> Error in doc_parse_raw(x, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html, : internal error: Huge input lookup [1]

But I am not using any HTML or XML files.
I am getting this error only if the file has a large number of records.
With a smaller number of records, I don't get any error and can print the output in .docx format.

I am using `officer` & `flextable` packages for output.

Please execute the below code,it will generate 10000 records,but unable to print in the .docx format. It will show the same error as i mentioned. I am using R 3.5.3 version.

```
ord<-c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J')
srnum<-c('1' :'1000')
df<-expand.grid(srnum=srnum,ord=ord)
library(officer)
library(flextable)
myft <- regulartable(df, col_keys = names(df))
my_doc <- body_add_flextable(my_doc, value = myft)
print(my_doc, target = "path/ABC.docx")
```

How do I write a docx file from a dataset with a large number of records?